# BeyondCVS only opens in Text Merge on MAC OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, beyondcompare

I am running BeyondCVS with Eclipse on the MAC OS X.  I am using Wine Bottler on the MAC to run Beyond Compare.  When I open "Compare with" in Eclipse and Beyond Compare opens up, for some reason it always goes into text merge mode.  I would like it to go into text compare.  I have looked online and I have not found out how to have it open up text compare by default. I really only need text compare. I had read somewhere that this setting is in the default sessions of Beyond Compare but I have not found it.